# Entity Framework check if last login time is greater than two days

Tags: c#, frameworks, entity

I am trying to write a query, where I select user and I also want to check if his last login time is greater than two days. If yes, then I want to block this user, if no, the user remains not blocked.

Code snippet :

```
var query = context.Users.Where(x => !x.NotBlocked && x.LastLoginTime.Value.Days >= 2);
```

But unfortunately I know that code is wrong and I am currently looking to write it in a correct way using Entity Framework.

Comment: Replace your `2` with `DateTime.Today.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(2))` and remove the `.Days` and it should work (you could also use `DateTime.Now` if you want it to be accurate to the femtosecond\* instead of to the day)

Comment: You should also replace ```>=``` with ```<=```

Comment: @IvanGechev nope, a larger date is one more in the future, so by doing `x.LastLoginTime >= DateTime now but 2 days ago` were checking whether the last login happened less than 2 days ago, with it the other way around we'd be checking whether the last login was more than 2 days ago

Comment: From what @Matheo's question is, I get that he wants to check if any user that is ```NotBlocked``` has not logged in the last two days - block them. I might getting it completely wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **DateTime.Now.AddDays(numberOfDays)** to get the exact last values in the last 24 hour * numberOfDays

```
var query = context.Users.Where(x => !x.NotBlocked && x.LastLoginTime >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2));
```